# wg-ros-pkg port to diamondback

Tags: ros-diamondback, pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried building some of the pr2 packages yesterday and found a few are still using eigen, as opposed to eigen3. Looking at the SVN comments at https://code.ros.org/gf/project/wg-ros-pkg/scmsvn/, the packages appear to be in transition. So, this is not so much a question as much as I'm looking for affirmation that you WG-folk are still working on this... should I hold my breath, or make some of the necessary fixes in my local code base?

Thanks,
Sean

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9940/wg-ros-pkg-port-to-diamondback/) by [seanarm](https://answers.ros.org/users/443/seanarm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 753 on 2011-05-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The wg-ros-pkg repos is mostly ported to diamondback, including all released stacks.

In Diamondback the package eigen contains eigen3.  The eigen3 package was only a backport into cturtle.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-05-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0